# Attach files programatically using Global.SendEmail standard_quickAction in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, send-email, lightning-quickaction, global-actions, emailfileattachment

I have an LWC datatable where, upon clicking a button at row level, the default email composer needs to open as it does in SF standard related list. The documentation specifies an example where HtmlBody and Subject can be provided as defaultValues in the email, however, I am unable to find which other possible values are available.

**I would like something to be able to automatically attach a file.**

I found this example related to Aura, but the similar thing does not seems to work when I tried in my LWC:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979336/how-to-add-an-attachment-to-the-sendemail-quickaction-api-through-lightning-comp

**Where can I find the documentation for the possible values?**

**Is it possible to achieve to automatically have a content document attached like this?**

Standard related list:

[image]
[image]

Custom approach with LWC (not able to provide attachment by default, and opens in modal):
[image]

Comment: Did you get any solution on this? Is it possible to attach a content document programatically? Or is it a limitation?